# How to Setup multiple user with htpasswd for docker registry that each of the has only access to their personal path?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, .htpasswd

I have a docker registry that uses htpasswd for authentication. I want to have multiple users each can only pull images from a certain path. For example:

user1 can pull images only from the below path

mydomain.com/v2/user1/

user2 can pull images only from the below path

mydomain.com/v2/user2/

right now each non admin user can pull from anywhere

Is there any way that can I fix it with htpasswd if not what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Distribution does not provide such level of granularity. You can build something yourself such a put a reverse proxy in front of the registry that has the logic you need or use a more advanced solution such as [Harbor](https://goharbor.io) or if you want it really light wight, maybe [trow](https://trow.io/) fits the bill as well.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth for implementing your own token server. Docker's docs walk through the process: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/.